# How does this work? LINQ to Entities triggers loading of assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

### Projects in solution

I have a typical 3-tier solution that targets .NET 4.5 and uses Entity Framework 6 Alpha 3. The solution is made up of three projects, let's call them:

1. **Entities** - class library containing the EF model and entity definitions
2. **DataAccess** - class library that acts as a 'business layer' between UI and database
3. **WinformsClient** - Winforms client application

### References

The WinformsClient project contains a lot of **external references**, including references to CrystalReports DLLs, other 'company wide' assemblies, etc.

Inside my WinformsClient, I have a reference to my DataAccess library. Both use the Entities library.

### Triggering the problem

From the WindowsClient, I call a method on the DataAccess library, let's call it `GetData`. Inside this method, a `DbContext` is created, some LINQ magic is performed and an `IEnumerable<T>` is returned.

### The issue

Now as soon as I call this method **for the first time**, a lot of external assemblies are loaded at the moment the first LINQ extension method is called. This includes the CrystalReports DLLs, which take ages to load. *But none of those assemblies are actually referenced by the **Entities** or **DataAccess** libraries or required to execute or display the data.*

In fact, when I create a separate Console Application that references the DataAccess and Entities libraries, I can call `GetData` and get my list of entities just fine, and no external libraries are loaded.

I suspect Entity Framework / LINQ to Entities has something to do with this, because when I simply return a list of POCO's from the DataAccess library (without loading EF), none of the exteral references are loaded.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

### Update

This issue is probably closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913275/how-to-prevent-ef4-from-dynamically-loading-all-assemblies), where Entity Framework tries to load all assemblies that are referenced from the project. Any suggestions to help me understand why this happens / how to influence this is still welcome!

Comment: Lazy loading? If you have virtual navigation properties and lazy loading is turned on (and it is by default) each time you access a property that has not been loaded yet EF will make a trip to the database and load the entities - this may trigger loading assemblies if required types have not been loaded yet. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx

Comment: Not to forget the initialization of the database model.

Comment: @Pawel I don't think so, because the Entity model is really simple at the moment (it contains only 2 entities, that are not dependent on any code that is in the external assemblies), and I don't access any navigation properties.

Comment: I don't know anything really about Crystal Reports but I believe that you're not going to get the load until it is needed, right?  So who is referencing CR in the code?  Is there some event that is being raised which results in code that references CR being executed, such as data being bound?  That's my initial thought on this.  .NET assemblies load JIT so it would seem that something is referencing that.  Some code might be helpful if you can post it.

Comment: Looks like something is triggering autodiscovery - try to check what's going on for example using procmon with filtering by process & file operations - will it enumerate *.dll (autodiscovery), or will it look for specific assemblies (something deeper inside)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on Entities or DataAccess layer, obviously, the issue is at your WinformsClient. My suggestion is that you set a breakpoint at the line thar calls the `GetData` method, that is obviously inside your WinformsClient project.

From there, step into the `GetData` method and check your call stack, maybe there you will find the offender. It's seems that the method that calls `GetData` is being watched by something in your WinformsClient app. (obs: too long for comment)

Comment: You're right, it is at the Winforms Client. However, the code itself does nothing other than referencing my Data Access library and calling `GetData`. So no obvious suspicious code there. Please see the update in my question...